# Filtering a dynamoDB query with a global secondary index

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using a Global Secondary Index to query my table and would like to be able to filter results based on other attributes (SQL equivalent would be a WHERE clause)). Scan allows me to do this, but is it possible with a Query? What other approaches can I take?

```
var params = {
                "IndexName": "City-index",
                "KeyConditions": {
                    "City": {
                        "AttributeValueList": [{
                            "S": city
                        }],
                        "ComparisonOperator": "EQ"
                    }

                },
                "Limit": "100",
                "TableName": "properties"
            }
            dynamoDB.query(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                }

            });
```

Any other ideas of how I can design a TABLE to achieve:

```
Hash Key: propertyID (unique)
Range Key: createdAt (unique

Global Secondary Indexes: City
Global Secondary Indexes: State
```

I'd like to be able to query by an Index and then filter by other attributes (bedrooms, bathrooms, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whichever attributes you need to query on needs to be made a GSI - You can add upto 5 of them. You need to also pay attention to the kind of queries it support (Only these: EQ | LE | LT | GE | GT | BEGINS_WITH | BETWEEN)

If your need is more than these queries, the Dynamo cant help - May be need to switch to RDS. If they can be formulated as documents, then consider Cloudsearch.

Comment: Thanks @Sony. A follow up to that then, can I query by more than 1 GSI at a time? I've tried this unsuccessfully. I would be fine with 5 but need to be able to query by multiple indexes in the same query.

Comment: Yes, I guess you can query multiple GSI in a single go - Hash Key, (and/or Range Key) and GSIs.

Comment: @Joe, If this has answered your question, can you mark as the correct answer ?

Comment: @SonyKadavan Nope, you can't query multiple GSIs in a single go, since you can only specify one Index table name.